# Limit accept type and charset on http inbound gateway

Tags: spring-integration

Is there a way to limit the type of messages that can be received using a http-inbound-gateway? In particular, accept and accept-charset http headers

thanks in advance
Guzman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with Spring Integration 3.0 the `<int-http:inbound-gateway>` supports `<request-mapping>` sub-element to provide options for your purpose.

It works the same way as `@RequestMapping` in the Spring MVC.

See Spring Integration [Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/http.html#http-namespace) on the matter.

It may looks like from the config perspective:

```
<int-http:inbound-gateway path="/consumes"
                 request-channel="consumesNonXmlChannel"
                 supported-methods="GET,PUT">
    <int-http:request-mapping consumes="!text/xml,text/*"/>
</int-http:inbound-gateway>
```

Comment: Thanks Artem! that worked fine but wanted to do the same with the produces="text/xml" but didn not worked. Is the same? <int-http:request-mapping consumes="text/xml" produces="text/xml" />

Comment: `consums` is for `Content-Type` HTTP header, `produces` is for `Accept` header. And both are from the Request.